# What are supported clients for an asp.net webpage?

Tags: asp.net, requirements

What are supported clients for an asp.net web page?

I am trying to document an asp.net website and I am unsure what I should say as far as client support.

Are there limitations for asp.net as far as browsers?  I have used IE and Firefox does it not work with some of the other browsers (chrome or safari)? Should I say the client is limited to any specific OS (I would expect it to work with a Mac or a Linux box)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can certainly limit "support" for a subset of web clients, you ought to be able to make it work for, at least, all modern web browsers to a greater or lesser extent.  The difference really has more to do with the web browser than the web site.  As far as dynamic behavior, I'd suggest going with a javascript framework that already addresses differences between major browsers.  CSS is more problematic, but you should still be able to approximate the same look and feel, though it may take some work.  Without knowing what specific problems you're having it's hard to know how to suggest that you solve them.  Generally, I would target and test IE 8/7, FireFox, and Safari (or Chrome).  You might want to throw in Opera as well, though my experience has been that if you get FF, you generally have already gotten it to work for Opera.

If you are having trouble with getting the generated HTML to work the way you want it to, you might want to try using ASP.NET MVC.  It gives you much more control over your HTML.  This can be really valuable in making things work the way you want it, though, WebForms code can obviously be made to work as well.  Sometimes, though, you have to jump through a few hoops to get it to behave exactly the way you want because the output of web controls isn't always what you and I would produce in every situation.

Comment: +1 for summary. @Maestro: To *approximate the same look and feel* checkout, css-reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in ASP.NET is inherently browser or client OS specific. So it should work on virtually any platform.

Obviously javascript support is nessessary for most ASP.NET sites to function correctly. However as the developer you can do many things both on purpose or by accident that may limit browser/platform compatibility. With the most obvious being using active-x controls.